# Deeplinking with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, deep-linking

On some websites (for instance http://www.guillaumebouvet.com/) every page of the site has a different php code. But when we change the page, page doesn't load from nothing but pages change with a transition.

I understand how to do it if the whole websites php code is written on a single page. But I don'r understand how every page has a different php code and pages change with transition.

Is this something we can do with .htaccess or is it something else?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: appears to be using the new history API to pushState into history without reloading. That and ajax. [more about history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: Thank You @JonathanKuhn for Your reply. But isn't there any .htaccess setting to direct links to the base file?

Comment: url_rewrite is used to map a requested URI to a page. You can very easily map any request to a single file which is what most frameworks do, map all calls to a single script and have that script route URIs to scripts.